# Azure: figure out if resource was deployed manually or via arm template

Tags: azure

Is there a way to figure out if resource was deployed manually (via Azure portal) or via arm template?

Comment: Programmatically or from the console?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your best option, although it won't guarantee 100% accuracy, is to look at the deployment name. If you look at a Resource Group from the Azure Portal and navigate to Deployments, you'll see a list of all deployments to that RG.

From my observations:

- if the deployment name is in the format Resource.Provider-Timestamp (Microsoft.RouteTable-20200824154745) it was done via the Portal
- if the deployment name is somewhat friendly or irregular (VirtualWanDeployment) it was a manual ARM template deployment (PowerShell in my case)
- if the deployment name is in the format resource-date-time-xxxx (applicationGateway-20200821-135645-bf71) it was an Azure DevOps pipeline

Comment: Unfortunately I have resources that were deployed via portal and via ARM in the same Resource group

Comment: that is not a problem, the names should help you identify which are which. At least that works for me.